# How can I configure the webpack or typescript that changes are made immediately?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, webpack

I've implemented webpack so that it generates one file from my angular application. webpack.js

Now the problem is whenever I change the TypeScript file, I'd have to re-run the webpack to see the effect.

That's slowed the development dramatically.

How can I configure the webpack or typescript that changes are made immediately?

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './app/main.js',
        vendor: './app/vendor.js'
    },
    output: {
        //path: './bin',
        filename: 'webpack/webpack-[name].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css'] },
            { test: /\.json/, loaders: ['json-loader'] },
            { test: /\.html/, loaders: ['raw-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, loaders: ['file-loader'] }
        ]}
     // Add minification
    , plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compress: {
              warnings: false
          },
          output: {
              comments: false
          }
      })
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use webpack-dev-server. It watches your source files and recompiles when changes are detected. https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html

Comment: Webpack also has a --watch command which, well, watches for changes and reruns the commands..

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure the webpack or typescript that changes are made immediately

Actually configure *how you run webpack*. If you use `webpack --watch` *it automatically updates the bundle* as soon as you make a change, but then *you still need to refresh the browser page*. Even better if you use `webpack-dev-server` as `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline` will even reload your browser page immediately.